# Android [string array] cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android

I'm getting an error about a string array (located in `strings.xml`) not being able to be resolved.

I've done everything the internet says:

1. Restarted Eclipse
2. Deleted my R.java file inside the `gen` folder
3. My `values` folder is still inside the `res` folder, not moved
4. None of my XML files have erros
5. Ran `Project -> Clean`
6. I don't have `android.R` imported in my class.
7. Checked the `R.java` class, it indeed doesn't have an `app_categories` property (my array's name)

The relevant part of the XML:

```
<string-array name="app_categories">
    <item >Cat 1</item>
    <item >Cat 2</item>
    <item >Cat 3</item>
    <item >Cat 4</item>
    <item >Cat 5</item>
    <item >Cat 6</item>
    <item >Cat 7</item>
    <item >Cat 8</item>
    <item >Cat 9</item>
</string-array>
```

The Java code:

```
String[] categoryNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.string.app_categories);
```

All my other strings are visible. I have another array defined just like this one, and that one isn't visible either.

Exact error below:

```
app_categories cannot be resolved or is not a field [class_name].java   [path]  line 45 Java Problem
```

Comment: @Abu Man, I *hope* that doesn't work, since it's XML, and XML shouldn't care about non-significant whitespace.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. Fortunately for the world's sake and unfortunately for me.

Comment: what error does it throw? can you paste that?

Comment: Check the import of "R" try to use package.R instead.

Comment: maybe, remove the projects from your work space then re - import.

Comment: Updated my question with the error. @EvZ I already did that under #6

Comment: @AidenFry Yes it is. I only pasted the relevant code, and as I said, the other string resources (not arrays) are working fine.

Comment: The resource name should begin with R.array, not R.string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just try out this way :

> ```
>  getResources().getString(R.array.app_categories_list);
> ```

Instead of `R.string` use `R.array` you will get your arraylist.

Comment: You are a God! Thank you. I thought the pattern was `R.[singular_of_file_name_in_which_resource_is].[resource_name]`, but it's obviously not.

Answer (score 4):

Don't put your string arrays in strings.xml You must create a new file called arrays.xml and place them there. 
And when calling you need R.arrays.myarray, not R.strings.MyArray

Comment: This is the solution I was going to post (you beat my by 30 seconds).  This is how I have my arrays setup and it works fine for me.

Comment: This helped me realize what the problem was, but it wasn't the solution for the problem per-se. I was calling `R.string.app_categories`, but I should have called `R.array.app_categories`. +1 for that

Comment: Type-specific naming of resource file doesn't matter. Its the xml tags which does.

Answer (score 0):

After cleaning your project try restarting the adb server by running adb kill-server and adb start-server from the command line

Answer (score 0):

a solution may be to create the R manually:

just hover over the error in the activity file where the problem was and then manually create it, which will cause R to generate the string array you created in *strings.xml*